# Forcing SSL on certain paths, and forcing no-SSL on all other paths with NGINX

Tags: ssl, nginx

How can I set up the SSL config for NGINX so that anything except for a few defined paths redirects to the non-SSL location?

My current config looks like this. It's set up for Django.

```
# Django Configuration
upstream prod {
    server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.mysite.org;
    rewrite ^/(.*) http://mysite.org/$1 permanent;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mysite.org;
    root /var/www/mysite.org/cache/;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/mysite.org.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/mysite.org.error.log;

     client_max_body_size 100m;

    #Static files location
    location ~ ^/(media)/ {
        root /var/www/mysite.org/html/;
        expires 30d;
    }

    # Send everyone to django initially
    set $django 1;

    if ($is_args = "?") {
        set $args_old ?$args;
    }
    if ($is_args = "") {
        set $args_old "";
    }

    default_type text/html;

    location / {
        include /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;

        if (-f $request_filename/index.html$args_old) {
            set $django 0;
        }
          if ($request_method != GET) {
               set $django 1;
          }

        # For authorized users
        # if ($http_cookie ~* "sessionid=([^;]+)(>:;|$)") {
        #     set $django 1;
        # }

        # Give back cache
        if ($django = 0) {
            rewrite (.*) $1/index.html$args_old break;
        }
        # Send to django
        if ($django) {
            proxy_pass http://prod;
            break;
        }
    }
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name mysite.org;

     ssl on;
     ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/mysite-final.crt;
     ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/mysite.key;
     ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    # access_log /var/log/nginx/ssl.mysite.access.log;
    # error_log /var/log/nginx/ssl.mysite.error.log;

     client_max_body_size 100m;

    #Static files location
    location ~ ^/(media)/ {
        root /var/www/mysite.org/html/;
        expires 30d;
    }

    default_type text/html;

    location / {
        include /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Protocol https;
          proxy_pass http://prod;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I cannot find instructions for this anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add this:

```
rewrite ^(.*) https://$server_name$1 permanent;
```

Towards the end of the location / section in your config.

Comment: Actually, he wanted it the other way: non-SSL for everything except a few paths.  This is actually a bit tricky to do in nginx.